# What does raise in Python raise?

Tags: python, exception

Consider the following code:

```
try:
    raise Exception("a")
except:
    try:
        raise Exception("b")
    finally:
        raise
```

This will raise `Exception: a`. I expected it to raise `Exception: b` (need I explain why?). Why does the final `raise` raise the original exception rather than (what I thought) was the last exception raised?

Comment: Python 3.1 raises both.

Comment: Ah. I should have mentioned I'm on Python 2.6.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: C# compiler on same combination says "Error: A throw statement with no arguments is not allowed in a finally clause that is nested inside the nearest enclosing catch clause" (throw == raise, catch == except). No ambiguity!

Comment: @Andrey but, I wouldn't expect the code to pose ambiguity. I expected the second exception to shadow the first. I used to think `raise` refers to the last exception thrown. I just learnt I was wrong.

Comment: @Andrey What was your question?

Comment: @aaronasterling i didn't ask any

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On python2.6

I guess, you are expecting the finally block to be tied with the "try" block where you raise the exception "B". The finally block is attached to the first "try" block.

If you added an except block in the inner try block, then the finally block will raise exception B.

```
try:
  raise Exception("a")
except:
  try:
    raise Exception("b")
  except:
    pass
  finally:
    raise
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
    raise Exception("b")
Exception: b
```

Another variation that explains whats happening here

```
try:
  raise Exception("a")
except:
  try:
    raise Exception("b")
  except:
    raise
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
    raise Exception("b")
Exception: b
```

If you see here, replacing the finally block with except does raise the exception B.

Comment: I have come to the same conclusion.

Comment: Indeed, this works! I'd have never guessed. Is this documented somewhere? Is this a feature or is it a necessity that comes from issues in the grammar?

Comment: Why doesn't the second exception merely shadow the first? I wish Python would err for syntax, or at least warn me about this.

Comment: wilhelmtell: `raise` is re-raising the last exception you caught, not the last exception you raised.  If you try `raise` by itself after throwing an exception and you haven't previously caught any exceptions, you'll get a TypeError since there's nothing to re-raise.

Comment: @wilhelmtell: I guess the doc may provide some answer to this. This does seem to have been corrected in Python 3. The behavior is different. Link : http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement

Comment: Your sentence `The finally block is attached to the first "try" block.` is very misleading, it's simply wrong from the syntactic perspective. Better concentrate on what `raise` is tied to. I think this should better be rephrased (maybe also the sentence before).

Answer (score 29):

> Raise is re-raising the last exception you caught, not the last exception you raised

(reposted from comments for clarity)